# Conditional rendering based on language: combining props and constants to render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code:

```
const ContactInfo = ({ language }) => {
  const engl = {
    yes: 'yes',
  };
  const fren = {
    yes: 'oui',
  };
  let text = null;
  if (language === 'engl') {
      text = <Text> {engl.ads} </Text>;
    } else {
      text = <Text> {fren.ads} </Text>;
    }

  return (
      {text}
      )
}
```

the 'language' props can either be 'engl' or 'fren'.
This works just fine, however, what I want to do is something like this:

```
return (
  <Text> {{language}.ads}
  )
```

So rather then using an if condition, I want to render whatever language is equal to and with that access my pre-defined objects.

My goal is to decrease the lines of my code. Is this possible?

In addition, is there any other robust way of dealing with multi language apps (other then server side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the 2 (or more) objects in one object that will act as a lookup table, then access the relevant key.

Here is a small running example:

```js
const titles = {
  engl: {
    yes: 'yes'
  },
  fren: {
    yes: 'oui'
  }
}


const App = ({ language }) => (
  <div>
    {titles[language].yes}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App language="fren" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

By the way, there is a great project by yahoo [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) that helps to manage this and much more:

> Internationalize React apps. This library provides React components
>   and an API to format dates, numbers, and strings, including
>   pluralization and handling translations.